# perl Coro shared array

Tags: perl, coroutine

I kind of newb in programming, and now little bit confused (well pretty much) about a simple task - share an array between coro coroutines.

Something like this (not working, just takes 40 secs to do)...

```
my @array = (1..1000);
$|=0;

sub start_thread($) {
    my $url = shift;
    return async {
        print "starting  $array[0]\n";
        shift @array;
        sleep(2);
      };
}

sub main{
  start_thread $_ for (1..20);
  EV::loop;
}

main;
```

I have read about IPC::Sharelite, and IPC::Share and tried some stuff, but nothing working... 
If somebody can clearly point me out please?

Comment: Is this the complete program?

Comment: Your program gives me the following error: `Can't locate object method "async" via package "2" (perhaps you forgot to load "2"?) at t.py line 6.`. Please post the entire source file (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @pts, He simply omitted `use strict; use warnings; use Coro;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coro is a co-operative multitasking system. That means that only one task can run at a time, and it's up to you to let other tasks run by using the event system (e.g. `$cv->recv`) rather than blocking calls (e.g. `sleep`).

```
use AE   qw( );
use Coro qw( async );

sub ae_sleep {
   my ($secs) = @_;
   my $cv = AE::cv();
   my $guard = AE::timer($secs, 0, $cv);
   $cv->recv();
}

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   my $id = sprintf("Thread %d: Job %s", $Coro::current, $job);
   print("$id: Running...\n");
   ae_sleep(2);
   print("$id: done.\n");
}

{
   my @array = 1..60;

   my @threads;
   for (1..20) {
      push @threads, async {
         while (defined(my $job = shift(@array))) {
            worker($job);
         }
      };
   }

   $_->join() for @threads;
}
```

If you use Coro::Channel instead of an array, you can add elements to the queue after you start your workers.

```
use AE            qw( );
use Coro          qw( async );
use Coro::Channel qw( );

sub ae_sleep { ... }  # Same as above

sub worker { ... }  # Same as above

{
   my $q = Coro::Channel->new();

   my @threads;
   for (1..20) {
      push @threads, async {
         while (defined(my $job = $q->get())) {
            worker($job);
         }
      };
   }

   $q->put($_) for 1..60;

   $q->shutdown();
   $_->join() for @threads;
}
```

If you wanted to use real threads, it's simply:

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue qw( );  # 3.01+

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   my $id = sprintf("Thread %d: Job %s", threads->tid, $job);
   print("$id: Running...\n");
   sleep(2);
   print("$id: done.\n");
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   my @threads;
   for (1..20) {
      push @threads, async {
         while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
            worker($job);
         }
      };
   }

   $q->enqueue($_) for 1..60;

   $q->end();
   $_->join() for @threads;
}
```

Comment: I was experimenting with sleep, as I though it's right way for concurrency tests,  how wrong I was it seems. 
With ae_sleep it just works.  For the rest in your example,  I need some sleep to put into my brains...

Comment: `sleep` doesn't know anything about Coro or the underlying event loop. it puts the only real thread the process has to sleep. `$cv->recv()` knows about Coro. It knows code is waiting to be run, so it will get Coro to switch context to that Coro thread.

Comment: Yes, I see (I think).

Comment: Well, I am not sure, but looks like there no benefits of using Coro for parallel download web content, because Parallel::ForkManager suits the task better.

Comment: P::FM will do great. but so will Coro since most of the time is spent waiting for data to arrive. If you want to use LWP with Coro, use LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http.

Comment: Just as offtopic, but since this time I was looking for something simple enough for me (without functional programming thing like say scala) and with minimum boileplate to get to this parallel things, and I found that Go matches my needs perfect.